# How to use variable as multidimensional associative array key?

Tags: php

I have an array that has a sub array I can access via

```
$fund['ManagersSets'][0]['PortfolioDate'];
```

I want to use a string variable for the array key. Something like:

```
$key = "'ManagersSets'][0]['ManagerBreakdowns'";
print_r($fund[$key]);
```

But get an undefined index notice when I run it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: no you can't do that

Comment: [You can](https://3v4l.org/uf4WU) - it's just not ideal :).

Comment: Both the above comments are correct. You *can't* do it because of how dangerous it *can* be but at the same time you *can* but you *shouldn't*, it just depends on how willing you are live life on the edge and *do* that which you *should not* be doing to achieve that which you *want* to do.

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be a string? You could do something like this:

```
$key = array('ManagerSets', 0, 'ManagerBreakdowns');
$result = $fund;
foreach($key as $index)
  $result = $result[$index];
print_r($result);
```

This does seem rather wacky and not really safe, but if you have to do it like that, you can.

If you really need strings, you can easily convert one to an array like that using `explode` or `preg_split`.

Again **I do not recommend that you use this.** It would probably be better to order your data differently.

Comment: Why is it unsafe?

Comment: If the input is string it can be exploded to an array like yours

Comment: Well, if that array doesn't have those indices then you will have null elements and probably an error. I guess, the same thing happens if you write `$fund['ManagerSets'][0]['ManagerBreakdowns']`, but you can check the second one easier

Comment: @Andreas Right, I always forget that split is deprecated, I will edit my answer to say explode

Comment: My understanding is, when you use the word **safe** you're referring to security issues and this approach does not seem to cause any security concerns. It might produce some empty index but that could be checked.

Comment: This solution looks perfect. You could then just simply add the checks to see if the key exists before advancing to the next iteration. If you want an unsafe solution look at my answer :p

Comment: The issue is not a security issue, that is correct, but I meant safe code as in code that is reliable even with bad input, and while it is completely possible and not too complicated to make it safe (using `isset`s and s.o.), this seems strange and, to me, a sign of a problematic design

Answer (score 1):

Just use three index variables:

```
list($ix_set, $ix_num, $ix_field) = ['ManagersSets', 0, 'PortfolioDate']; 
$value = $fund[$ix_set][$ix_num][$ix_field];
```

Comment: This isn't very dynamic. I think OP is looking for something that can work for more than one condition

Comment: I'm glad, that it isn't, because too much dynamism can be a pain in the ass

Answer (score 0):

With your line `print_r($fund[$key]);` What you're asking from PHP is accessing the key `'ManagersSets'][0]['ManagerBreakdowns'` from the array fund which doesn't exist. There is a key `ManagersSets` but no key `'ManagersSets'][0]['ManagerBreakdowns'`

You can't ask PHP to access a variable series of indexes from an array in one instruction like this.

What you **can** do but you **shouldn't do** if you want to achieve something like that is calling `eval()` like this :

```
$fund = ['ManagersSets' => [['PortfolioDate' => "2017-09-26"]]];
$fund['ManagersSets'][0]['ManagerBreakdowns'] = [1, 2, 3];

$key = "'ManagersSets'][0]['ManagerBreakdowns'";
print_r(eval('return $fund[' . $key. '];'));
```

the code above will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

But the reason why you shouldn't do this is that if the value inside `$key` variable is dependent to user input, if someone managed to put malicious code inside it, it will be executed as is.

For example if

```
$key = "'ManagersSets'] &&
    file_put_contents('/tmp/test', 'Oops!') ||
    \$fund['ManagersSets'";
```

trying to do `print_r(eval('return $fund[' . $key. '];'));` will result in printing `1` **AND** writing "Oops!" in `/tmp/test`. And that's just a small example, I let you imagine what a hacker can do with such power.